# How to make sets of iterators

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to iterate over a certain range and create several sets that contain only the current i. (In the code I don't want to do this for every i, but it's about the general principle).

```
for i in range(5):
    s=set(i)
    print(s)
```

It says int object is not iterable. Why doesn't this work? Please keep the answers simple, I'm a newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set()` takes a *sequence* of values to add, and a single integer is not a sequence.

You could wrap it in a tuple or a list:

```
s = set((i,))
s = set([i])
```

but the better option is to use the `{..}` set literal notation:

```
s = {i}
```

The notation looks a lot like creating a dictionary, but you only list values, not keys.

Demo (on Python 2, where the representation uses `set([..])` notation):

```
>>> i = 42
>>> set((i,))
set([42])
>>> set([i])
set([42])
>>> {i}
set([42])
```

Python 3 reflects sets using the literal notation:

```
>>> i = 42
>>> {i}
{42}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set constructor `set(x)` requires `x` to be some container, like a list, or other set. You pass an integer, python tries to iterate over it, and fails.

In order to do so you need to pass a singleton of x, like that:

```
for i in range(5):
  s = set([i]) # or s = set((i,))
  print(s)
```

or through simplified set constructor

```
for i in range(5):
  s = {i}
  print(s)
```

or construct an empty set and add your element

```
for i in range(5):
  s = set()
  s.add(i)
  print(s)
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of using a for loop in range, you can also feed it to set (or a frozenset if you dont need to change it's content):

```
>>> set(range(5))
# {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```